# How to repeat code if invalid data is entered

Tags: c#, repeat

I need to make this code which calculates a Parking Fee give an error and ask the user to re-input the data if a false number is provided. For example if the user enters an amount that is less than 1 or greater than 24, an error code will appear and ask the user to re-enter a valid amount. Once a valid amount is entered I'd like it to output the parkFee.
I haven't updated my Pseudocode so apologies about that.

```
    /* PSEUDOCODE */
    /* HOURLY_RATE=2.5
     * INPUT parkTime
     * parkFee = HOURLY_RATE * hours
     * OUTPUT parkFee */


        decimal parkTime;  // input - time in hour eg 1.5 for 1 and a half hours 
        const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.50m; // HOURLY_RATE * INPUT parkTime = parkFee
        const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00m; // MAX_FEE is set as a payment cap and ignores any extra charges incurred over 8 hours
        decimal parkFee;
        Console.WriteLine("ParkingFee1 program developed by: Ryley Copeman");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your total time parked in hours: Eg 1.5 or 3.0");
        parkTime = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (parkTime > 8)
        {
            Console.Write("Total fee is $" + MAX_FEE);
        }
        else
        {
            parkFee = Math.Ceiling(parkTime) * HOURLY_RATE;
            Console.Write("Parking Fee = $" + parkFee);
        }
        while(parkTime < 0 || parkTime > 24)    // validate... 
        //while (parkTime <= 0) )
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Error – Park Time out of range");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter - Park Time between 0 and 24 (HOURS):");
        parkTime = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to [SO] :-) I've taken the liberty of removing your tag from your question title, as per [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need this:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your total time parked in hours: Eg 1.5 or 3.0");
    parkTime = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (parkTime < 1 || parkTime > 24)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error – Park Time out of range");
    }
}
while (parkTime < 1 || parkTime > 24);

if (parkTime > 8)
{
    Console.Write("Total fee is $" + MAX_FEE);
}
else
{
     parkFee = Math.Ceiling(parkTime) * HOURLY_RATE;
     Console.Write("Parking Fee = $" + parkFee);
 }
```

Note that you may want to adjust the code to always calculate the fee, and then apply the maximum:

```
parkFee = Math.Min(MAX_FEE, Math.Ceiling(parkTime) * HOURLY_RATE);
Console.Write("Parking Fee = $" + parkFee);
```

Here `Math.Min` will choose the smallest of the two values.

Finally, note that `decimal.Parse` will error if you enter something it doesn't expect (e.g. "1.2Hello", or ""), so it might be better to use `TryParse`:

```
bool isValidTime = false;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your total time parked in hours: Eg 1.5 or 3.0");
    bool parsedOK = decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out parkTime);
    isValidTime = parsedOK && parkTime >= 1 && parkTime <= 24;
    if (!isValidTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error – Park Time out of range");
    }
}
while (!isValidTime);

parkFee = Math.Min(MAX_FEE, Math.Ceiling(parkTime) * HOURLY_RATE);
Console.Write("Parking Fee = $" + parkFee);
```

Here the loops will continue until a valid value is entered. Note that in loop structures you can also use `break;` (leave the loop), and `continue;` (move to the next iteration of the loop) to control the flow.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help John. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome :) Feel free to accept my answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: Hey John - I have a quick question. Let's say - I have entered an invalid number and get the "Park Time out of Range" error. I then enter for a valid number e.g. 16 hours. How do I get it to output the correct answer (parkFee).

Comment: Using the second example above, it should exit the loop once you have entered the correct time, and then the code below will output the fee.

Comment: @RyC I've created an example using a queue to simulate user input (since dotnetfiddle isn't interactive): https://dotnetfiddle.net/myvchj

Answer (score 1):

As you already know about the concept of loops, there are a few possibilities, the simple one is a loop with `break`.

```
for (;;) {
  // input
  if (condition ok)
    break;
  // output "wrong, try again"
}
```

This will repeat the input as often as necessary and quit the loop once accaptable values are entered.

Answer (score 1):

```
 /* PSEUDOCODE */
    /* HOURLY_RATE=2.5
     * INPUT parkTime
     * parkFee = HOURLY_RATE * hours
     * OUTPUT parkFee */

        bool mustRepeat = true;
        decimal parkTime = 0;  // input - time in hour eg 1.5 for 1 and a half hours 
        const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.50m; // HOURLY_RATE * INPUT parkTime = parkFee
        const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00m; // MAX_FEE is set as a payment cap and ignores any extra charges incurred over 8 hours
        decimal parkFee;
        Console.WriteLine("ParkingFee1 program developed by: Ryley Copeman");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your total time parked in hours: Eg 1.5 or 3.0");

        while(mustRepeat)    // validate... 
        {
            parkTime = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if(parkTime < 1 || parkTime > 24)
            {       
                Console.WriteLine("Error – Park Time out of range");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter - Park Time between 0 and 24 (HOURS):");
                continue;
            }

            mustRepeat = false;

            if (parkTime > 8)
            {
                Console.Write("Total fee is $" + MAX_FEE);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                parkFee = Math.Ceiling(parkTime) * HOURLY_RATE;
                Console.Write("Parking Fee = $" + parkFee);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see what you're doing there but the last three  "Console.WriteLine("Error- Park Time out of Range"); is giving an error saying that it's unreachable.

Comment: I don't see any problem, it work fine. Just parkTime should check with <= 0 or < 1
I change the code to fix it

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("ParkingFee1 program developed by: Ryley Copeman");
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your total time parked in hours: Eg 1.5 or 3.0");
parkTime = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
do
{
    if(parkTime < 1 || parkTime > 24)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error – Park Time out of range");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter - Park Time between 0 and 24 (HOURS):");
        parkTime = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        continue;
    }
    if (parkTime > 8)
    {
        Console.Write("Total fee is $" + MAX_FEE);
    }
    else
    {
        parkFee = Math.Ceiling(parkTime) * HOURLY_RATE;
        Console.Write("Parking Fee = $" + parkFee);
    }
} while(parkTime < 1 || parkTime > 24);
```